# 3 wires in 3cables, each black, white and ground inside one plastic enclosed switchbox that has inside slots no screws being replaced

Tags: light, multiway-switch

SITUATION: replacing 3 lever switch box connected to one outlet.

Inside one of the 3 switchboxes (1) lever this switchbox had 4 plastic non-screw interior connectors called slots instead of screws. I opened this first switchbox that turns on/off the wall outlet by switching up/down.
The other 2 switchboxes each operate the interior living room fan and outdoor light.

Inside this 1st switchbox I found 3 black wires and 3 white wires and 3 ground wires in 3 white cables. I saw one of the 3 white wires had a small black band marking.
I started replacing this switchbox with an appliance that says it is Two Switches, by LEVITON. I hooked 2 black wires by twisting them together and attached them to one gold screw. I hooked the 3rd black wire to the 2nd gold screw. all of the black wires are on one side of of this new 2 switches appliance.
I hooked 2 white wires that I twisted together to the 1st silver screw and the 3rd white wire to the 2nd silver screw on the other side of the new 2 switches 15a-120/277 ac/ca appliance.
I took all 3 ground wires twisted them together and attached them the green ground screw provided inside the new switchbox.

Results: have  no outlet power and no light, other lower outlets work in home but no light switches work.

What do I do to get them working all again? I cannot use old switchbox because the mechanism for the on/off selector is broken.

[image: dual light switch]  [image: broken switch box]

[image: 5 contacts inside switch box]  [image: 5 contacts inside switch box]

[image: above new dual switch]  [image: new dual switch at an angle]

[image: opposite side new dual switch]  [image: old paddle switch]

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why did you disassemble the switch itself? They really aren't (as far as I'm aware) designed to be repaired but simply replaced.

Comment: I presume by the "NM-B" labeling on the cable that you're in the US. Please be aware that the installation you have, with the wire running from the wall directly into the switch without the protection of a plastic or metal junction box does not meet code and is not safe! This is something that you'll definitely want to address as any sort of short circuit or loose connection could start a fire that will immediately jump to that stud and could burn the building down!

Comment: Replacing your self-contained "mobile home switch" https://www.starsupplyusa.com/collections/mobile-home-light-switches-receptacles-covers/products/pass-seymour-white-self-contained-rocker-wall-switch-es-2329 with a standard switch will require adding a junction box. The biggest problem you will have is that in the replacement box you are required to have 6" of conductor (or 4" if Manufactured Home CFR 3280), and often there is not enough wire to do that. It is best to replace with identical replacement device, your best option to find a local source may be an RV parts supply company.

Comment: Many electricians have no experience with these devices. If this is a HUD/Manufactured Home and you ultimately need to call an electrician you may run into other issues that will cause you to need to politely and tactfully remind him that the Code for MH's is CFR 3280 which is based on NEC 70-1993 or 70-2005 with many exceptions. Some electricians get real bent out of shape trying to comply with something other than newest NEC.

Answer (score 2):

Realize when you don't know what you are doing, and get some books and skill up.  This is gross "blundering around", and you need more skill to even do this work. Get help or get skills.

> I saw one of the 3 white wires had a small black band marking.

See, that eye for detail is more than half of it.   The black band means, specifically, that this not a neutral wire.  This is being used as a hot wire for a "switch loop".

The only reason to bring a switch loop *to this switch* is to switch it.  Which means the black and marked-white in this cable are the only wires that should be attached to this switch.   The other wires appear to be unrelated?  Doesn't make a lot of sense.

> I started replacing this switchbox with an appliance that says it is Two Switches, by LEVITON.

Why???? Changing 1 switch to 2 switches *makes no sense whatsoever* unless you have a plan you are not telling us about. Are you wiring in a new lamp or device that you also want to control here?  No, you said you're replacing it because it's broken.  I don't know.

> I hooked 2 black wires by twisting them together
> I hooked 2 white wires that I twisted together
> I hooked 2 white wires that I twisted together

That is NOT a proper way to splice wires.  Obviously, the old switch provided a splicing method.  Since your new one does not -- you MUST use "wire nuts", lever-nuts, push-in splices or other such device, and **pigtail** to the switch if you are wiring it that way.

> From comment by NoSparksPlease: Replacing your [self-contained "mobile home switch"](https://www.starsupplyusa.com/collections/mobile-home-light-switches-receptacles-covers/products/pass-seymour-white-self-contained-rocker-wall-switch-es-2329) with a standard switch will require adding a junction box.

That's true. *A complication here, for your education*, is that this is a trailer/manufactured home.  They use weird stuff because it is cheaper and faster to assemble. The "self contained switches that make their splices by squeezing" is one of those weird things you won'd find out about from normal skill-building.

Yes, you will need to either a) use that exact same type of switch (which was kindly linked for you), or b) pull out all 3 switches, install a 3-gang junction box, and install normal switches in all 3 positions.  This will involve 5-7 Romex cables and *sophomore level* skills at wire identification, so you'll need even more skill building before you're ready for that.

You have *just enough* wire length to go that way, so don't waste any wire length!

> I hooked 2 white wires that I twisted together to the 1st silver screw and the 3rd white wire to the 2nd silver screw on the other side of the new 2 switches 15a-120/277 ac/ca appliance.

SMH, it's not an "appliance", it's a **switch**.  You never, ever hook neutral to a switch, and that should be obvious.

You really need to start with the basic electrical skills here.  I have no doubt that you can handle it -- it's just that you *have not handled it*.   Handle it.